# Time-travelling neo-Nazis try to give Hitler an H-bomb

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction, time-travel

A group of neo-Nazis steal an H-bomb (that looks like a briefcase) from a museum in the future, with the intention of going back in time and giving it to Hitler in 1944 or 1945 (near his defeat), to turn the tide of the war.

The time travel is actually a (future) tourist attraction. They are spaceship-like machines that launch into space, then travel back in time, and the tourists may view the historical happenings from Earth's orbit, with some heavy-duty binoculars IIRC. They are not allowed to land for fear of changing the past.

The neo-Nazis either make a clandestine deal with a time machine (spaceship) pilot, or possibly replace the pilot with one of their own, so that they may land and attain their goal. They land into a snowy landscape, eventually run into some Nazis and manage to make some sort of contact with the leadership. However,

> it seems they got the year wrong and are not exactly greeted as saviours.

There is a second group of people from the future who learn of the neo-Nazis' plans and try to stop them. Usual time-travel hijinks happen: Multiple versions of the same people, each trying to stop a previous self or something to that extent.

- Country: Czechoslovakia (?)
- Approximate year: 1970s?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Zítra vstanu a oparím se cajem](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0213322/?ref_=ttpl_pl_tt) (1977)

English title: Tomorrow I'll Wake Up and Scald Myself with Tea

> Former Nazi Klaus Abard survives to the 1990s by taking anti-aging pills. He plans to use a time travel trip to return to Germany in 1944 and present Hitler with a hydrogen bomb, so that he can win the war. Unfortunately the pilot, woman-chasing Karel Bures, dies on the morning of the trip and his earnest twin brother Jan impersonates him, without knowing about the plot. The plot goes wrong when they lose the bomb and land near Hitler's bunker in 1941, at a time that the Nazis sense victory. Bures, with two of the plotters, escape capture by the Nazis and make it back to the time machine. Bures programs the machine to return one day before they left, because he figures he can then save his brother and foil the plot.

Comment: That title is lovely.